# Woocommerce Product Filter Не работает фильтр описания категории

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

есть сайт на WP + WOOF (Woocommerce product filter), сортировка работает хорошо, однако при сортировке (ajax) он сортирует товары, но не меняет описание атрибутов (в самих атрибутах есть поле описания, нужно чтобы оно выводилось и изменялось в зависимости от выбранного атрибута в фильтре). 
На данный момент выводится в самом каталоге /shop/ описание категории, если выбрать  какой-нибудь 1 фильтр, описание категории пропадает, но не выводится описание самого атрибута, как сделать чтобы в зависимости от выбранного атрибута изменялось и описание?

Comment: Покажите на картинке, что вы хотите. И сразу вопрос - а почему вы думаете, что такой функционал должен быть в WOOF?

Comment: @KAGGDesign 1. Вот заполнено описание категории в админке - http://prntscr.com/lsq1gz, на сайте вывод по урлу http://site.ru/catalog/ - http://prntscr.com/lsq125. При нажатии на любой атрибут в фильтре к примеру - цвет - светлый, описание должно отображатся из атрибута "светлый" внизу, но описание категории (что первый скрин пропадает) и внизу ничего не вводит - http://prntscr.com/lsq1xe. Урл же динамический Ajax - http://site.ru/catalog/?swoof=1&pa_tsvet=pod-derevo&really_curr_tax=37-product_cat . Из разбора урл полуается что последнее &really_curr_tax=37-product_cat - это ID идет категории

Comment: а не атрибута, насчет функционала как-то это можно сделать, он получает ul = products и сортирует их, и затрагивает текст раз он пропадает, но не выводит описание самого атрибута я просто не знаю как...